# How do I copy data to a new tab that is automatically created by a Google Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have created a Google Script that automatically creates a new tab on a Google Sheet when triggered each month. Now I also need to copy all data from another tab on the same sheet to the newly created one. The source tab will be used as the template for each new month that is copied. I want to try to `IMPORTRANGE` on each new tab that is created, but I am unsure how to copy the data.

Below is the code that is currently running.

*Q*: What additional code do I need to include to copy the data from my template tab each month?

Thank you

```js
function newTab(){
  var dateObj = new Date();
  var month = dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1; //months from 1-12
  var day = dateObj.getUTCDate();
  var year = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();
  var name = month + "/" + year;

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()

  ss.insertSheet(name);
  ss.getSheetByName(name);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
function newTab(){ 
  var name=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/yyyy") 
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); 
  var templateSheet=ss.getSheetByName('*******TEMPLATE SHEET NAME HERE********'); 
  ss.insertSheet(name,{template:templateSheet}); //The S in sheet was not capitalized like it is in the declaration.  Sorry for that.
}
```

[insertSheet(name, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#insertSheet(Integer,Object))

Comment: Thanks for this Cooper. I have run this script, and I get just a new blank tab still, but I am unsure as to how I need to write in the exact code for the specific tab I am trying to copy. The Google Sheet name is 'Month2' the tab is 'TEMPLATE' and the cells I need to copy are from 'A1:D50'. Are you able to let me know how I would write that information into your code so that the information is copied over? Thanks again

Comment: templatesheet was not supposed to be a string.  I just changed that.

Comment: Unfortunately I still wasn't able to get that working. I tried amending it according to my sheets, but haven't got it working. Here is what I tried

Comment: function newTab(){
  var name=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/yyyy")
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var templateSheet=ss.getSheetByName('1o-bXZ1aRfe3RIDl964uRf6Q5ASGH9T1DIlFehh14_gk');
  ss.insertSheet(name,{TEMPLATE: A1:D50});
}

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't sure how to format the code in the comment box. I'm incredibly new to all this!

Comment: Now copy it exactly as written.  The options were in an object.

Comment: I am now receiving an error that says 'ReferenceError: "templatesheet" is not defined. (line 5, file "Code")'

Comment: Okay that string in this line `var templateSheet=ss.getSheetByName('1o-bXZ1aRfe3RIDl964uRf6Q5ASGH9T1DIlFehh14_gk');`is supposed to be the name of your templatesheet. Which has to be in ss.

Comment: Sorry, still not getting anything with this. Really appreciate your help with this Cooper

Comment: So, the spreadsheet is called 'Month2' which has a tab called 'template', and its that tab that I am trying to copy into the newly created tab each month

Comment: Did you read the link below the answer.  That's what I'm suggesting that you do.

Comment: OK, I missed that. I had a quick look just now, but still can't make any sense of it unfortunately. I'll have a good look over the link and hopefully will get it up and running. Thanks

Comment: All you have to do is add the name of the template sheet and you're done.

Comment: Hi again, I tried this again, and I’m not getting it. I have the google sheet saved in my template folder, and I have copied the sheet ID that is part of the url for the sheet and I’ve added it where you have marked ‘TEMPLATE SHEET NAME HERE’. I have kept everything else exactly the same. When I run the script it creates a new blank tab that is named by the date, but without any data on the sheet. I’m sorry if I’m missing something really obvious here and I really appreciate your help

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in the answer.  It definitely works now. I just tried it myself.

Comment: This a fairly easy bug to spot.  I know it was my fault and I'm sorry, but these are the sort things that you going to have to learn to contend with if your interested in learning how to program in any language.  The reality is that we make mistakes and in some ways it's good because we become a lot better at finding them.  You really need to look closely at code and pay attention to what the error says and what line it's on.  And you really need to understand how to use all of the debugging tools.  The only programmers that don't make mistakes are dead programmers.

Comment: Ah Cooper, it worked perfectly! Thank you so much for your help, and I totally agree with your comments. I have absolutely no knowledge of coding, and I just wanted an answer, but this exercise has really made me a lot more interested in learning in more detail so that I am able to spot mistakes. This has been a massive help for a project I'm working on, so thanks for your time with helping on this!